# How to return a pointer array from a function

Tags: c#, arrays, pointers, unmanaged, unsafe

I wonder how it is possible to return a `2 Dimensional pointer array for outArray`?
I am not sure how to declare and implement this in this example.

`function1(ptr, out outArray);`

```
    unsafe private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[,] inputArray = new byte[10, 100];
        byte[,] outArray;
        fixed (byte* ptr = inputArray)
        {
            //How to return a 2 Dimensional pointer array for: "outArray" ?
            function1(ptr, out outArray); 
        }
    }
    unsafe void function1(byte* ptr, out byte[,] outArray)
    {
        outArray = new byte[10, 100];
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need unmanged code solution? [Look](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref)

Comment: I am using `Vector128/SIMD instructions code` So I have to use `unsafe` code. In that code I have to use `pointers`

Comment: Are you getting a compile error from the code in your question?  If yes, what error?  If no, what is the code doing "wrong" when you run it (explain what it does do and what you wanted it to do instead)

Comment: There is no compile error. This code works but in my example the `function1` returns a normal 2 Dimensional array and not a 2 Dimensional pointer array. I am looking for if it is possible to return a 2 Dimensional pointer array for: `out byte[,] outArray`

Comment: [`System.Numerics.Vector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector-1?view=netcore-3.0) is actually managed SIMD imlementation. In case you're not in .NET Framework :)

Comment: I am using `using System.Runtime.Intrinsics;` `NET core 3.1`. I also need to use pointers for those `Vector128` that I use.

Comment: Anyway, look at the `System.Numerics` namespace. There are more vectors. Finally, do benchmarks to compare unmanaged and above Vector.

Comment: Btw, `out` keyword is for managed code. Afaik, you may pass pointer for result data in the same way as you pass input data there.

Comment: I have compared `Intrinsics` and `System.Numerics` with alot of benchmarks and in my tests the `Intrinsics` is much faster somehow. But is it true that it would be wrong to `out` a pointer in this case. I just wonder if it is possible. I really don't know how to write it as no idéa that I have compile. Passing it as the input data does not seem to compile there.

Comment: I haven't any exerience in unmanaged things. But I suggest to add revealed in comments information to the question and `unmanaged` tag. Maybe it will call more attention to the question.

Comment: Yes no problem lets see if anyone else have any idéa. I added `unmanaged` and `unsafe` to the tags. It was a good idéa. Thank you.